# Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm just trying to retrieve JSON data from a Firebase Realtime Database and display it onto a text view

and i'm not sure why is this happening,have added gms,applied plugins in gradle both project level and module level,this is my MainActivity.java
Sorry for adding this into JSSnippet

Any Help would be appreciated

```js
package com.example.halo.firebase;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TextView MagTxt;
    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    private DatabaseReference mRootreference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
    private DatabaseReference mChildreference = mRootreference.child("message");
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MagTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msgTxt);
        MagTxt.setText("Refreshing Data...");



    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    mChildreference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       String Message = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        MagTxt.setText(Message);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    }
}
```

```js
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.example.halo.firebase, PID: 18428
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.halo.firebase/com.example.halo.firebase.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.halo.firebase. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2567)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.halo.firebase. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
                                                                               at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.example.halo.firebase.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:16)
                                                                               at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1079)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2557)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Did you add the google-services.json in your project root-level folder?

Comment: yep,added both in project and app folder

Comment: Then you can try this `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)` in your Application's `onCreate()`. But it should work without it.

Comment: it seems initializeapp is depricated,i've used getinstance() instead of that

Comment: all right,got it working,the json file had a space in between,removed the space everything is fine

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is that you instantiated your `FirebaseDatabase` and `DatabaseReference` in the open.

You should create the variables then instantiate them in the `onCreate`.

Like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // without instantiation

    private TextView MagTxt;
    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mRootreference;
    private DatabaseReference mChildreference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // instantiate in the onCreate method

        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mRootreference = firebaseDatabase.getReference();
        mChildreference = mRootreference.child("message");

        MagTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msgTxt);
        MagTxt.setText("Refreshing Data...");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    mChildreference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
       String Message = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        MagTxt.setText(Message);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


    }
}
```

Hope that helped.

Comment: i dont think so,anyways lemme check

Comment: Nope,same result :(

Comment: all right,got it working,the json file had a space in between,removed the space everything is fine